# Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
public class ListFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] arr = {"text", "tekl"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);     
        List<String> listt = Arrays.asList({"text", "tttt"});
        }
}
```

Line 4 is totally working fine. However, line 5 gives error: "Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token" at column 36. 
Is the argument passed as `{"text", "tttt"}` is considered as block here?

Comment: Try `Arrays.asList(new String[]{"text", "tttt"})` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `Type[] arr = { …, … };` that's an [*array initializer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6). It can only be used in array declarations (or in array creation expressions, i.e. `new String[]{"a", "b"}`).

`Arrays.asList` is defined to take varargs arguments (`asList(T... a)`), so you do not have to wrap your arguments in an array first: `Arrays.asList("text", "tek1")` will already implicitely create an array from your arguments and pass this to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing possible correct synthax. These are the possibilities you want to specify:

```
List<String> listt = Arrays.asList("text", "tttt");
```

or

```
List<String> listt = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"text", "tttt"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert something invalid in Arrays.asList.
Try to use

```
List<String> listt = Arrays.asList("text", "tttt");
```

From Java 8 javadocs

> **asList**
>
> @SafeVarargs
>
> public static  List asList(T... a)
>
> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts
>   as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in
>   combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is
>   serializable and implements RandomAccess.
>
> This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements:
>
> List stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
>
> Type Parameters:
>
> T - the class of the objects in the array
>
> Parameters:
>
> a - the array by which the list will be backed
>
> Returns:
>
> a list view of the specified array